# Ubuntu 22.04 problem with monitor resolution

Tags: display, 22.04, display-resolution, monitor

My ubuntu worked well with a VGA 1920x1200 resolution monitor and the previous version of ubuntu, but when upgrading to 22.04.1 LTS it only supports 1024x768 maximum. The system is an intel I7 with Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) table. The script that worked previously no longer works. The script is :

```
#!/bin/sh cvt 1920 1200 
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00" 193.25 1920 2056 2256 2592 1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync 
xrandr --addmode DP-1 1920x1200_60.00 
xrandr -s 1920x1200
```

What can I do? Thanks

Comment: xrandr only works for xorg, but Ubuntu 22.04 defaults to Wayland for display capability. You can switch back to xorg if you must use xrandr

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Esther.  `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

and

set WaylandEnable=false

`enter code here`sudo systemctl restart gdm3
#!/bin/sh cvt 1920 1200
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00" 193.25 1920 2056 2256 2592 1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1 1920x1200_60.00
xrandr -s 1920x1200
enter code here

and resolution is ok